# Compute the following Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I've been sitting on this question for a while now:

Let $f(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Compute 
$$
\lim_{h\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx.
$$

I've managed to convince myself that the solution is $2 \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|$. However, it alludes me of how to make this a quick and easy.  Any way I can thing this approach this problem begins with taking a continuous functions with compact support and approximating the integral with this.  Do anything have a more slick way to think about this problem?

Comment: The solution should be $0$. Approximation via $C_c$ functions sounds reasonable. Use the dominated convergence theorem of Lebesgue to switch limit and integral.

Comment: @Zardo It's the limit as $h\to \infty$, not $h\to 0$.

Comment: Alright. Still this should work

Comment: No, it's $h \to \infty$, I promise. The one when $h \to 0$, I was able to do without much pain.

Comment: Through an approximation argument, for each $x$, $f(x+h)$ is "basically eventually zero" (in the sense that it is eventually zero for any $C_c$ approximant) so I would think the answer should be $\| f \|_{L^1}$. But I may be missing a detail.

Comment: @Zardo what is "this" in "this should still work?" It's definitely *not* zero, as setting $f$ with compact support will make clear.

Comment: @Ian This would happen, if you first took the limit and then integrate. You do it the other way round and you don't have a global majorant allowing Lebesgues theorem.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Denoting the integral by $I_h(f)$, if $f$ has compact support with diameter $M$ and $h>M$ then $I_h(f)=2 \| f \|_{L^1}$. (This is basically because $f(x+h)$ and $f(x)$ are never both nonzero.) Now suppose $f_n$ have compact support and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Then $I_h(f)=I_h(\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n)$, so $\lim_{h \to \infty} I_h(f)=\lim_{h \to \infty} I_h(\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n)$. Try to figure out whether you can interchange limits to get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{h \to \infty} I_h(f_n)$ (which is definitely $2 \| f \|_{L^1}$).

Comment: Also note that without loss of generality you can assume $f_n \to f$ both a.e. and in $L^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first that $f$ has support in some $[-a,a].$ Then for $h> 2a,$

$$|f(x+h)-f(x)| = |f(x+h)|+ |f(x)|,$$ simply because these functions have disjoint supports. It follows that

$$(1)\int|f(x+h)-f(x)| = 2\int|f|$$

for $h>2a.$

Now let $\epsilon > 0.$ Then, by the DCT, we can choose $a>0$ such that $\int|f-f\chi_{[-a,a]}|< \epsilon.$ Set $g =  f\chi_{[-a,a]}.$ Then

$$\int|f(x+h)-f(x)| \le \int|f(x+h)-g(x+h)| +\int|g(x+h)-g(x)| + \int|g(x)-f(x)|$$ $$ < \int|g(x+h)-g(x)| + 2\epsilon.$$

Therefore

$$\int|f(x+h)-f(x)| - 2\int|f| \le \int|g(x+h)-g(x)| - 2\int|g|+2\epsilon .$$

Now apply $(1)$ to $g$ to get

$$\limsup_{h\to \infty} \left( \int|f(x+h)-f(x)| - 2\int|f| \right) \le 2\epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the $\limsup$ above is $0.$ A similar argument shows the $\liminf $ is $\ge -3\epsilon$ or so. Thus $\int|f(x+h)-f(x)| \to 2\int|f|$ as desired.